# memory leak issue at browser with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory-leaks

I have a struts based web application with ajax calls instead of page refreshes. Every time I return some ajax content, it replaces the content on the main div.

```
function execcmdcallback(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
{
    $("#divmain").html(data);
    data = null;
}
```

Each time this executes, the browser memory(specially the IE) increases by about 600-900kb.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this where the old memory is freed so there is no significant increase in browser memory on each ajax call ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

That is only some data, no images, no widgets etc, i have 4 tables having some data and that is for help desk dept of the application, it user create some ticket/request my table1 get populated, and this ticket moves from table to table till completion. so simple data is there in all table, that is not getting increased much more, but just shuffling the tables only.

Comment: There can be many reasons for the increasing memory. Do you have any `<script>` tags in the data you load ?

Comment: @t.niese no there are not any script tage, i did some R&D for that see this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12231/Memory-Leakage-in-Internet-Explorer-revisited

Comment: That link (codeproject) can't be up to date, its from 2005, I can't believe a 8 years old bug didn't get solved

Comment: How big is the `data` ? maybe it requires quite a bit of rendering?

Comment: Do you use another library beside jQuery, do you have e.g. google widgets in the page or some other external content that uses another library that is not based on jQuery or do you probably include two jQuery versions? Are new images loaded? Does the memory increase if you switch multiple times between the same content?

Comment: @nrathaus most of the bugs are solved in IE 9 (standart mode). But still - at least im pretty sure - remain when IE is in compatibility mode.

Comment: What you are describing, is a serious issue, 600kb every time this simple line is called? that doesn't sound like a small bug

Comment: Please see the edited. hope this will help a bit more